# std_beta() is not a function from namespace - cannot find function in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, lme4

I'm trying to compute the standard betas for my regression using `std_beta()`, but simply **R doesn't find the function**. I've loaded both [sjstats](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjstats/versions/0.17.7/topics/std_beta) and [sjmisc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjmisc/versions/1.8/topics/std_beta), but R still doesn't find the function. **Any ideas?**

- code:

```
library(sjmisc)
library(sjstats)

> sjmisc::std_beta(model, ci.lvl = 0.95)
Error: 'std_beta' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sjmisc'
> sjstats::std_beta(model, ci.lvl = 0.95)
Error: 'std_beta' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sjstats'
```

- `help` doesn't work too:

```
?std_beta()
Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 
  no methods for ‘std_beta’ and no documentation for it as a function
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and came across this [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjstats/news/news.html).

So instead of `std_beta()`, you can now use `effectsize::standardize_parameters()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an older version [`sjstats 0.17.2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjstats/versions/0.17.7/topics/std_beta) like this:

```r
library(remotes)
install_version("sjstats", version = "0.17.2")
library(sjstats)
sjstats::std_beta()
#> Error in UseMethod("std_beta"): no applicable method for 'std_beta' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: hi! so, I'm still geting the same message :c

Comment: Hi @LarissaCury, Are you sure you are using an older version? On Github you can see that the latest version doesn’t contain the std_beta version.